# Increase and Decrease an AWS CloudWatch graph

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm fairly new to AWS CloudWatch and never set up a custom graph before. Is it possible to have one that displays a count that is simply incremented and decremented.

My idea was to create a graph for a queue (not an SQS queue) and I want to simply be able to make a request to tell AWS to lower the count by one when a job finishes and add 1 to the count when it's complete so I can then autoscale processes based on the demand of the queue. Is it possible to do this as I've seen count metrics and event metrics but I feel my use case kind of sits between and I'm unsure what terminology to be searching for?

I've seen some stuff about doing Sums of events but again, would that work if I want to take away the processed count?

Answer (score 0):

yes - you could publish a metric with the value of the "total" you want to monitor, but that would require you to keep the current count in your application.